# Unable to delete some files after script crashes

Tags: matlab, file, delete-file, parfor, matlabpool

I run a MATLAB script which generates images, saving them into a certain folder. When the code crashes, I cannot delete a few images in that folder unless I restart MATLAB.

Can I solve this problem *without* restart MATLAB program?

Code:

```
clear,clc,close all
SRC1 = 'SRC1';
SRC2 = 'SRC2';
suffix1 = '_suffix1.png';
suffix2 = '_suffix2.png';
DST = 'DST';
GT = 'GT';
FEAS = {
    SRC1;
    };
feaSuffix = {
    '_suffix.png';
    };
if ~exist(DST, 'dir')
    mkdir(DST);
end
if matlabpool('size')<=0
    matlabpool('open','local',8);
else
    disp('Already initialized');
end
files1 = dir(fullfile(SRC1, strcat('*', suffix1)));
parfor k = 1:length(files1)
    disp(k);
    name1 = files1(k).name;

    gtName = strrep(name1, suffix1, '.bmp');
    gtImg = imread(fullfile(GT, gtName));
    if ~islogical(gtImg)
        gtImg = gtImg(:,:,1) > 128;
    end
    gtArea = sum(gtImg(:));
    if gtArea == 0
        error('no ground truth in %s', gtName);
    end

    img1 = imread(fullfile(SRC1, name1));
    mae1 = CalMAE(img1, gtImg);

    name2 = strrep(name1, suffix1, suffix2);
    img2 = imread(fullfile(SRC2, name2));
    mae2 = CalMAE(img2, gtImg);

    delta = mae1 - mae2 + 1;
    preffix = sprintf('%.2f_mae1_%.2f_mae2_%.2f_', delta, mae1, mae2);

    imwrite(img1, fullfile(DST, strcat(preffix, name1)));
    imwrite(img2, fullfile(DST, strcat(preffix, name2)));
    imwrite(gtImg, fullfile(DST, strcat(preffix, gtName)));

    for n = 1:length(FEAS)
        feaImgName = strrep(name1, suffix1, feaSuffix{n});
        copyfile(fullfile(FEAS{n}, feaImgName), ...
            fullfile(DST, strcat(preffix, feaImgName)));
    end
end
```

Comment: This is because you are not closing the image files you open in your matlab code. Can you update your question with your matlab code?...

Comment: Actually, I only 'copyfile' and 'imwrite' to that folder. How can I release resources related to those image files? I tried 'clear all', but it did not work.

Comment: Please give the code which you are using.

Comment: code is now edited, thanks!

Comment: Seems like you still have some image files open by MATLAB. Try to close them all with `fclose all` command in matlab prompt. Does it help?

Comment: Also what do you mean by "code corrupt"? are you sure `imwrite()`s have completed and are not still under progress when you try to delete the files?

Comment: corrupt means matlab stops for a reason such as a file cannot be found.

Comment: fclose('all') does not work

Comment: Since the file access takes place inside the `parfor`, that means the worker that crashed needs to run it, or kill the workers.  See my updated answer.  I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can tell MATLAB to close any open files with

```
fclose('all');
```

In my experience [`fclose`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fclose.html) applies to all opened files, not just ones opened with `fopen`.

Also, since you are running a `matlabpool`, each worker (MATLAB.exe process) will need to release their files.  To do this, I suggest creating a `try`-`catch` inside the `parfor` like this.

```
parfor k = 1:length(files1)
    try
        % your loop content here
    catch ME
        % cleanup and terminate
        fclose('all');
        rethrow(ME);
    end
end
```

This way, the worker that bombs out in the loop will run `fclose`.  Running it in the master MATLAB.exe probably will not be helpful.

However, you can also **make sure you close the `matlabpool`** before you try to delete the files since this should release any file locks that the workers have.

Comment: See my updated answer to address the `matlabpool` aspect.  The file reading takes place in the workers, which are independent MATLAB.exe processes, so they need to be killed or release their file locks with `fclose`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it sounds reasonable.